# Protractor issue: click() function isn't working

Tags: angular, protractor, end-to-end

I have one senario the button click function is being used by lot of e2e cucumber test cases. I am able to get the text of the button. But if clicking its not redirecting or loading any contents.

```
var next = element(by.cssClass('buttonclass'));
next.click();
```

The above code is not working but if I am using `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",next )`
then the click is working. I cant change the code since its being used by multiple test cases.... What will be the reason?

Comment: my angular application is interacting with a non angular app for authentication (sso). i am making angualr enabled to false for this .... after this protector start behaving abnormal. that wont wait for control to load.... everywhere await putting is a tedious task..sometimes that will wait for long time and timeout will happen. any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
var next = element(by.css('buttonclass'));
```

Comment: my angular application is interacting with a non angular app for authentication (sso). i am making angualr enabled to false for this .... after this protector start behaving abnormal. that wont wait for control to load.... everywhere await putting is a tedious task..sometimes that will wait for long time and timeout will happen. any other suggestions??

Comment: have you try explicit wait ?

Answer (score 0):

When building tests, its really important to find/interact with only with "single" element on your page.

Meaning, you have to find elements by locators: css,xpath.. etc and the result to be only "*one*" element, if you start to see "*more than one element found, will use the first..*", this indicates you need to rework the locator.

Another good practice is to use the "wait conditions".

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Before click, be sure the element condition is met: elementToBeClickable

If you have complex website not always protractor commands can do the job. In that case use javascript executor.

Comment: my angular application is interacting with a non angular app for authentication (sso). i am making angualr enabled to false for this .... after this protector start behaving abnormal. that wont wait for control to load.... everywhere await putting is a tedious task..sometimes that will wait for long time and timeout will happen. any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

**WHY** it's happening

likely the element you're referring to is a wrapper, for example

```
<div id="id">
  text
  <button></button>
</div>
```

In this case, if you click on `div` in the UI the `button` will get the click because it overlaps the button. When you do it with protractor it clicks exactly the element you specify. SO you can get text from `div#id` but if you click it tells you this element is not clickable. This type of script `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",next )` doesn't care about the page layout and will click the element even if the element is invisible in UI

**Solution**

you HAVE to be able to control your scripts, if you can't change the click in one place, then your code is not flexible enough and you need to think how to improve it